# Why do I get inconsistent exceptions on Python?

Tags: python, exception, ioerror

I encountered a very strange behavior in Python, a behavior that is not consistent.

```
...
except IOError as msg:
    sys.exit("###ERROR IOError: %s" % (msg))
```

Usually this would get me a message like:

```
###ERROR IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'filename'
```

In same cases the above code is giving me a `tuple` instead of a proper error message.

```
###ERROR IOError: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

This is very strange because in all case the exception come from the same python method, `codecs.open(...)`

What makes me wonder more about this is that if I remove the handling the exception will reach upper levels with the right text (full error message), always!

```
except IOError as msg:
    print(msg)
    raise msg
```

The above example will *always* print a complete message, like `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'filename'`.

Why is this happening and how do I prevent this, I don't want to give incomplete error messages to the users.

I wanted to reproduce this behavior in a test file, but I was not able to reproduce this outside the project.

I suspect that is has something to do with the usage of `sys.exit()` because `print(msg)` will give good result but `sys.exit` not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, when reraising an exception, *never* do `except Exc as e: raise e`. It is *always* just plain `raise` with no arguments. This will preserve the traceback.

No, this has nothing to do with `sys.exit` and everything to do with how the exception was instantiated. You *are* always getting an exception; just sometimes its string representation will resemble that of a `tuple`.

```
>>> print IOError(13, 'Permission denied')
[Errno 13] Permission denied
>>> print IOError((13, 'Permission denied'))
(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Without showing the full traceback, there's no way to tell what exactly is raising the error in this way. Also, without properly reraising like I pointed out, you won't be getting the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Before Python 1.5 exceptions were strings. After that they changed it to classes to maintain backwards compatibility. Nowadays you can only raise exception instances or classes.

I imagine there was a code like this:

```
error = (13, 'Permision denied')

#more code

raise error
```

After they changed it to exception somebody just did:

```
raise IOError(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't depend on the string representation of the exception; you might name it `msg`, but it's neither a string nor a message; it's an exception instance.

So you might want to construct your own string from the `msg.args` tuple, and use that as the “message” you want to display.